# two images with camera position and angle to 3d data?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

Suppose I've got two images taken by the same camera. I know the 3d position of the camera and the 3d angle of the camera when each picture was taken. I want to extract some 3d data from the images on the portion of them that overlaps. It seems that OpenCV could help me solve this problem, but I can't seem to find where my camera position and angle would be used in their method stack. Help? Is there some other C library that would be more helpful? I don't even know what keywords to search for on the web. What's the technical term for overlapping image content?

Comment: What you are trying to do is called stereo vision. I don't know exactly how to do this in OpenCV, but there should be plenty of information out there now that you know what to look for.

Comment: As I understand it, stereo vision implies two cameras pointing at one target. I have a that situation slightly inverted: one camera pointing at two different targets with some overlap.

Comment: You can do stereo vision with one camera, but it does have to be of the same target, so you are right that your situation is different. Could you upload some example images and specify what kind of 3D data you want to extract?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn a little more about camera geometry, and stereo rig geometry. Unless your camera was mounted on a special rig, it's rather doubtful that its pose at each image can be specified with just an angle and a point. Rather, you'd need three angles (e.g. roll, pitch, yaw). Plus, if you want your reconstruction to be metrical accurate, you need to calibrate accurately the focal length of the camera (at a minimum).

Comment: I have the roll, pitch, and yaw. That's what I mean by "3d angle".